# JavaScript Web Socket error code 1006

Tags: javascript

Can't create web socket connection, always get an error code 1006.

```
var socket = new WebSocket( 'ws://google.com', ['soap', 'wamp'] );
socket.onopen = function()
{
    socket.send('text');
};
```

Comment: Sure, why do you expect a valid connection at `ws://google.com`?

Comment: For example. IRL I try create connection with localhost.

Comment: So, what WS server is running at your localhost? Please show us what you're actually trying, not some arbitrary google url.